# Lazy load modules conditionally on the basis of HTTP response in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

I have two roles admin and user. I have to load the admin page if userId belong to admin and user page if that userId belong to user.

The URL is something like `http://example.net/[user_id]`.

Is it possible that I can lazy load the modules in Angular routes on the basis of http response I get? I hit the API and pass the User Id and get the user role then I have to load the lazy load its module.

Comment: see if [this](https://www.technouz.com/4644/angular-5-app-structure-multiple-modules/) helps.. i have incorporated this into an application for work.. this is quite useful

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. You can however do a redirect in a guard on the `:user_id` route:

```
export class UserRoleResolve implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  public async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
     const userId: string = route.params.user_id;
     const role: string = await this.getRoleFromUser(userId);

     if (role === 'admin') {
       this.router.navigateByUrl(`/admin/${userId}`);
     } else if (role === 'user') {
       this.router.navigateByUrl(`/user/${userId}`);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for workaround. can you please explain how you will define this functions.  const role: string = await this.getRoleFromUser(userId);
you have used await keyword. what it will return? an observable ?

Comment: I'm sorry. I've updated my answer a bit. Seems like I mixed up Resolve and CanActivate. Anyways, by using `await/async` you can get cleaner code. But only when you use promises. The implementation of how you get the role from the user is up to you. I just gave it as an example :)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem with this: PreloadingStrategy.